# Chrome extension for Facebook, need to reload page

Tags: jquery, facebook, google-chrome

I'm trying to create a chrome extension to catch the click on any link in facebook.com

This is the script, very simple:
(it needs jquery)

```
$( "a" ).on( "click", function(eventa) {
   console.log(eventa);
   console.log(this);
   console.log($(this).attr('class'));
});
```

I have the problem ONLY with Facebook.

The problem is:
If I click on any link after opening www.facebook.com, it works great but if I click on any link after reaching a new page it doesn't works.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try to use:

```
$(document).on( "click","a",function(eventa) {
   console.log(eventa);
   console.log(this);
   console.log($(this).attr('class'));
});
```